# Static dictionary for Java Deflate

Tags: java, compression

I have a need to compress postal address information which is typically around 120 or so bytes long. Each record must be compressed separately since accessed in a random access fashion.
Java's Deflater has a set dictionary method which takes a byte array. But how does one generate a static dictionary that's a byte array?

USA postal addresses have a very regular frequencies for the characters.

I've searched high and low looking for example code without luck. So let's say I have a frequency chart for the ASCII characters used, how does one build the dictionary which is a byte array to be passed to the Java Library?

For this application the speed of compression is the most important.

*UPDATE*

I found an example:

http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=PowerTutor/src/edu/umich/PowerTutor/service/PowerEstimator.java

```
 /* A dictionary used to assist in compression of the log files.  Strings that
   * appear more frequently should be put towards the end of the dictionary. It 
   * is not critical that every string that be written to the log appear here. 
   */ 
  private static final String DEFLATE_DICTIONARY = 
      "onoffidleoff-hookringinglowairplane-modebatteryedgeGPRS3Gunknown" + 
      "in-serviceemergency-onlyout-of-servicepower-offdisconnectedconnecting" + 
      "associateconnectedsuspendedphone-callservicenetworkbegin.0123456789" + 
      "GPSAudioWifi3GLCDCPU-power ";
```

And I found the dictionary string is limited to 32k.

My current thinking is to build a frequency chart of various n-grams.  The weight of each n-gram will the length*frequency.

Comment: Do you mean to construct a HashMap where the key is postal address and value is something else?

Comment: No. The setDictionary(byte[]) method takes a byte array.

Comment: A clue: http://www.javased.com/index.php?source_dir=PowerTutor/src/edu/umich/PowerTutor/service/PowerEstimator.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you can do is look for commonly occurring strings in your data, and populate the 32K with those strings. That's all there is to it. As noted in the reference you found, the compression will be better if the most common strings are towards the end of the 32K, and the least common towards the start.

The benefit of the dictionary has nothing to do with character frequencies, but rather with matching strings. If the compressor can find a string in the dictionary of three or more characters, it can replace that string with a reference to the dictionary, which is a distance and a length. (Shorter distances code in fewer bits, hence putting more common strings at the end of the dictionary, which is closer to the data being compressed.)

Character frequencies are already handled dynamically by the Huffman coder, which is independent of the dictionary.

I don't have your list of addresses, but you can look for common city, state combinations, possibly including the first few digits of the zip code. You can look for common address components, like " Ave.", spelled out ordinal numbers like "First", "Second", street names like "Main", "Hill", "Lake", "Elm", etc. Those could be combined, e.g. "First St.", "Main St.". Possibly quadrants " NE ", " SW ". Note the inclusion of spaces as part of the string to be matched.

Comment: Deflator doesn't appear that code for my purpose. :( I did as you mentioned and my sample only compressed 11%.  That is too poor to bother with. I suspect that a pre-built huffman tree would work better. I am only using a set of 40 chars out of 256, so I think I should get nearly 80% compression on my short strings...

Comment: inputString=inputString.replace(" ", "X");
BigInteger bd=new BigInteger(inputString,36);
byte[] byteArray = bd.toByteArray(); This already compressed by 35%

Comment: 40 characters of equal frequency, out of 256, would compress 8 bits to 5.3 bits. Not 80%. I doubt that you have only 36 characters, unless your addresses have no spaces. Or maybe no "Z"'s.

Comment: zlib does not provide a facility for pre-built Huffman trees.

Comment: I just took a large set of addresses, converted it to all upper case, and computed the entropy to be 4.75 bits per character. You won't compress to the entropy, so you should expect no better than about 5 bits per character.

Comment: Strictly for my purposes, I don't need spaces or punctuation. I took some huffman encoder code and tested it, and I was able to 44% compression on a static huffman tree. I am little surprised there isn't a standard library to do this...

Comment: Mark Adler, by the way, I am honored that you posted on my question. I noticed that you invented Adler-32!